# make custom templated ListBoxItem to be the same width as ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am trying to make my listbox to have the same width as the window here is a minimum example.

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" Background="Blue">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock Text="test" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The result looks like

[image]

Where the blue part is the list box and the black parts are the rows. I am trying to make the rows to have the same width as the listbox

Comment: HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"?

Comment: @Will already tried, no luck. Had horizontal stretch on every single element I can apply it on

Comment: Set `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` on the ListBox, not on the ListBoxItem.

Comment: Should work.  Don't see how it wouldn't.  I'd examine the visual tree at runtime either using the xaml debugging tools in 2015 or using Snoop or similar.

Comment: If you edit to show a minimal example where you use the HCA property, and show in a screenshot that it isn't working, I'll reopen and add an example where it does.

Comment: @Will setting it on ListBox solved the problem. Thanks